# 45 minutes boot

Tags: boot

Lately my boot time is becoming very slow.
I suspect that it has something to do with the nvidia drivers.
It is stuck in a loop for 45 minutes trying to detect GPU:

here is the tail of the boot log:

```
===========================================================
(2 of 2) A start job is running for Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
(2 of 2) A start job is running for Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes
(1 of 2) A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit (45min 13s / no limit
(1 of 2) A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit (45min 16s / no limit
[  OK  ] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Starting Light Display Manager...
======================================================================
```

And here is the gpu manager log:

```
sudo cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log
==============================================================
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log 
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot  
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot  
grep dmesg status 0  
dmesg status 0 == 0? Yes  
grep dmesg status 256  
dmesg status 256 == 0? No  
Is nvidia loaded? no  
Was nvidia unloaded? yes  
Is nvidia blacklisted? no  
Is fglrx loaded? no  
Was fglrx unloaded? no  
Is fglrx blacklisted? no  
Is intel loaded? yes  
Is radeon loaded? no  
Is radeon blacklisted? no  
Is nouveau loaded? yes  
Is nouveau blacklisted? no  
Is fglrx kernel module available? no  
Is nvidia kernel module available? no  
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:416  
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"  
Is boot vga? yes  
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1292  
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"  
Is boot vga? no  
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nouveau"  
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"  
Found "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nouveau"  
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card1: 0  
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nouveau"  
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"  
output 0:  
    eDP connector  
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1  
Does it require offloading? yes  
last cards number = 2  
Has amd? no  
Has intel? yes  
Has nvidia? yes  
How many cards? 2  
Has the system changed? No  
main_arch_path x86_64-linux-gnu, other_arch_path i386-linux-gnu  
Current alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf  
Current core alternative: (null)  
Is nvidia enabled? no  
Is fglrx enabled? no  
Is mesa enabled? yes  
Is pxpress enabled? no  
Is prime enabled? no  
Is nvidia available? no  
Is fglrx available? no  
Is fglrx-core available? no  
Is mesa available? yes  
Is pxpress available? no  
Is prime available? no  
Intel IGP detected  
Desktop system detected  
or laptop with open drivers  
Discrete NVIDIA card detected  
can't access /etc/X11/xorg.conf  
Driver not enabled or not in use  
Nothing to do  

=====================
```

not sure if relevant, lspci shows nvidia 3D controller (and other things):

```
3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
```

again, not sure if relevent. systemctl status gpu-manager.service shows:

```
gpu-manager.service - Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpu-manager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since ד' 2015-11-11 00:07:08 IST; 13h ago
Main PID: 840 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Update:
I rebooted and again it took 45 minutes. What does this mean? I understand that some process is looking for the GPU and it cannot start the desktop until it finds it or gives up, and it seems like it gives up after 45 minutes. Is there some place where a time interval for "give up" is defined?

Please help me understand whats going on and how to fix it.

Comment: In addition to the answer, if it doesn't fix your issue, did you recently install `plymouth-manager`?

Comment: I don't know. I did not install it manually. I updated Ubuntu to 15.10 a few days ago.

Comment: If you didn't install it manually then you probably didn't install it. Just figured I'd check instead of writing out an answer that only had a small chance of being accurate.

Comment: Had the same issue. Deleted a 23G syslog file and got a normal boot time.
Not sure if this related but the issue started very soon after I changed to a new external monitor connected using HDMI.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by itself. 
I don't know why or how.  The last action I did before the last reboot was rm /var/log/syslog; rm /var/log/ufw.log and rm /var/log/auth.*
becuase each was taking 100GB.  If anybody can explain what happened then please post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated)
After you boot into your distro-

1. Download the latest drivers with

   ```
   wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/352.55/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.55.run
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   sudo ./NVIDIA-x86_64-352.55.run
   ```

   and click OK on everything.

Comment: I want to understand what is happening.  Why is the boot sequence stuck for 45 minutes looking for something and eventually it starts the lightdm and works fine.  There must be a way to make it do the same in 2 minutes or less.. (limit the spawn trials?). I'm kind of new to Linux so I don't want to mount/dismount.

Comment: No need to worry about the mount command. It does the same thing that the bootloader does for you at the system startup. You won't mess up your disk IF you follow the instructions closely.

And more often than not, its just a package issue which cases these problems, and saves a lot of pain to just reinstall them than to repair them.

Comment: I saw in the comments that you updated your distro to a newer version (using terminal I'm guessing). That is why the newer distro's GPU settings tried to overwrite your previous ones. Thus, reinstall is the most recommended solution to that.

Comment: You want to learn more about your distro, and you are averse to mount? That is a bit ironical. And I reiterate - mounting is NOT an issue. You're file manager does that when you open a file anyway. Running the rm or delete command is when you should be a bit concerned.

Comment: Hello Goelakash, I have visited the link you have posted and it reads 
"How To Fix A Non-Bootable Ubuntu System Due To Broken Updates Using A LiveCD And Chroot "but My Ubuntu is Bootable. (it takes 45 minutes but its bootable). I just want to know why it loops for 45 minutes before it gives up and uses an alternative, why not 2 minutes?

Comment: I've edited the answer. I thought you wouldn't want to wait 40 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

I found this was happening after plugging in an HDMI projector. I was using the Intel driver. The presentation went fine. The previous plugging caused no issues. Though this time on next boot, the window manager would not start. Found the `/var/log/gpu-manager.log` had been smashed into having unusual ACL and timestamp.

```
p--xrwsrwx  1 mail       1711       0 Jan 26  1971 gpu-manager.log
```

Deleted the zero-bytes log file and the window manager started ok.